# How to validate American Phone Format in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextField that accepts a phone number
i want to validate it if that is an american formatted phone number.
i know that in swift you have an out of the box fix for that ?

do you know of a regex or a way fo validate that that can work on swift 4 ?

Comment: Phone number validation is kinda tricky thing, so I advise you to use some ready-to-use pod, like [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) instead of writing own ad-hoc validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
(\\([0-9]{3}\\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```

Code:

```
let phoneNumber = "+1 (123) 456-7890" //Replace it with the Phone number you want to validate
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: phoneNumber.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\([0-9]{3}\\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")
if regex.firstMatch(in: phoneNumber, options: [], range: range) != nil{
    print("Phone number is valid")
}else{
    print("Phone number is not valid")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression

```
^[1{1}]\\s\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$
```

Use like this :

```
isValidMobile(testStr : "1 555-555-5555")
```

> This will return `true`

```
isValidMobile(testStr : "1 555-555-55555")
```

> This will return `false`

Function will be like this :

```
func isValidMobile(testStr:String) -> Bool {        
    let mobileRegEx = "^[1{1}]\\s\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"
    let mobileTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", mobileRegEx)
    return mobileTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Comment: @ChiefMadog Please check my updates ans..it work for me